# General vue.js. deployment with lambda

Tags: express, vue.js, deployment, aws-lambda

I have a question about deployment strategy with vue.js + express.js + lambda.
I can deploy express.js to lambda with serverless as backend. and then where can I deploy vue.js as frontend? I saw some kind of article. They deployed S3 and domain forward to S3 bucket. Is this common way?

I mean If I make html file in express.js and deploy to lambda. that's just one shot deployment. Can I deploy like this with vue.js?
thanks for answering in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy your frontend (be it in Vue, React, Angular) via S3 by [Hosting a Static Website using Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html)

Your frontend can then invoke API Gateway which will trigger your Lambda functions (which happens to be the backend of your application)